# ASP.NET MVC Generic User Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, controls

I created a generic user control in vanilla ASP.NET:

- Via a set property, it takes a bunch of metadata from page A, or B, or whatever parent page it happens to exist on.
- There are sometimes multiple copies of this user control, each copy working off distinct metadata of course, on one page.
- In code-behind the user control, based on its metadata, dynamically renders child elements as necessary.

I'm now looking into ASP.NET MVC.  Today being the first day of such activity, I have no idea how the generic-ness of this user control could be ported over.  Do pages have a one-to-one relationship with controllers?  How about user controls?  Would my generic user control link directly to one or more controller(s)?  If so, how is this linking assigned?  Or would each controller just pass view data to the user control?

Can anyone give me high-level design thoughts for my scenario?  Or point me to helpful links?

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy...

The concept of Asp.Net mvc also goes hand in hand with RESTful style website structure. I'm not going to bother with explaining MVC over again, since there are great articles such as http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx

As for user control, the whole concept is that you shouldn't be duplicating and providing the same functionalility on all the pages. Instead, you'd create a partial view, and make that partial view POST data to a particular url.

Then you have multiple form elements on the page all posting to the specific URL that each provide the functionality for that part of the page.

E.G. A log in box
-> a form element with login/password input that post to /Account/Login

A register box
-> a form element with name/email/password input that post to /Account/Register

etc etc.

You really need to ditch a lot of stuff you learned in WebForm to get started with MVC.

Edit- I believe the best way to learn MVC is to get in there with a small project and get started. Also a piece of advice. Asp.Net mvc has a lot of "conventions" you want to follow.

Eg. default page at /home/index. default page is /index. the folder naming structure.

Granted you can change all those, but you are just wasting time usually.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you expand on the advantages of MVC with respect to the functionality I described?  I'm having trouble seeing the big picture of how MVC would improve what my generic user control is already doing reasonably well in vanilla ASP.NET.

Comment: Haha, there isn't. MVC does have the disadvantage in regard to packaging a user control. The whole idea of MVC is to decouple View from Model from Controller. So you can't, theoretically, package those together.

Comment: I'd suggest you get the basics for the MVC down first. There is ways to achieve what you are after, but it's very convoluted. For now, if you want modularity like user controls, I suggest you go with WebForms. Maybe look up one of those MVVM frameworks to use on WebForm to have better and more consistent seperation of concern.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just to point you in a direction, you can look at the following:

Loading a View from serialised source (such as sql/resource embedded string) via custom view engine.

OR Custom Html helper extension method.

one of those two and

Custom Controller factory/activator (to serve up a controller + action outside of the MVC website or in a referenced bin file)

A way to hook events into your custom user control. First thing that cross my head is Dependency injection. (Injecting a service into the controller action you package up as the controller for the serialised partial view)

So, in order to use a "granular, self contained" user control, you'll need those infrastructure in place, and the control packaged in a special way.

Or you can just use plain old user control in MVC. I think that works (google it up)

Comment: Those are, when you get more familiar with MVC :P. If you just started out, no need to go into those.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts to get you rolling.  Hope this helps.

- In thinking about MVC, think of the "View" as the traditional "Page" without the code behind. The "View" has controls and HTML and other rendering specific logic.
- The traditional code behind is replaced with a "Model".  Controller contains the logic to decide with object instance of the model is passed to the "View"
- "Controller"s are not hardlinked to any view.   The best way to think about it.  Controller can handle multiple "Action"s.  The handling code for each "Action" can return a "View".  This is the "View" that is rendered to the user.
- A view can be shared across multiple actions within a controller and as well as across controllers.
- You have the flexibility of decomposing your view into partial views (similar to master page/content page notion)

From that point of view,  here is a possible way to proceed.

Take a couple of your .aspx pages and change them to views.  While doing so try refactoring the code in codebehind into models.  Any code you find that calls the database and creates data object to be rendered, move them into the controller.

Take a simple case of your generic user control and convert it to a view and get it working as a partial view with the above .aspx pages that you converted to views.

The excercise should give you good sense for what your porting options are.